# World city list API for frontend

Tags: api, search

I'm building a mobile app such that user can type the name of a city and brings up suggestion based on what he/she has typed. This is feature that Bumble has as shown below. My question is that do I need to have a list of cities on a server somewhere to do so? Or is there a good city name API service out there? If I decide to build my own search service, any reference that I can get the list of cities in the world?

Thanks for any comments/answers. I appreciate it a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question for people who might have the same question. Google Places API provides what I need. For ReactNative, check out react-native-google-places-autocomplete module at https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete